# Why System.out.print(ternary operator) print float in output?

Tags: java, floating-point, conditional-operator

I was going through some java interview questions MCQ where I found this code snippet, of which I didn't understand the output, though its only a 2 line code.

```
int a = 8;
System.out.println(((a<8)? 9.9 : (int)9));
```

Output is 9.0
I didn't understand why it is not 9 ?

Comment: java is a statically typed language, which means among other things that any expression has a type. What type but a floating-point number one could it have here? As 9.9 is a possible result value of this expression, a whole number type is incapable to do.

Comment: try `System.out.println( (int)((a<8) ? 9.9 : 9.0));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not casting all of them . you are just casting second result to int.

But don't forget first result is float so all of structure must be same type.
You need to cast all of them as same type like int or float.

```
int a = 8;
System.out.println(""+ (int)( (a<8)? 9.9 :  9));
```

output :

```
9
```

Answer (score 3):

Ternary operator has return type that is defined before the calculation of the value.
So, if the operator can return both float and int, then the both values are upcasted to the float.
Your answer is casted in this way:

```
(int)9 -> (int)9 -> (float)9.
```

Other situation: If you add float and int, you get float

```
int a = 2;
float b = 4.3f;
float c = a + b;
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the ternary operator is determined according to quite complicated rules:
[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25). Specifically, in your case:

> Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.

So in your case you get return type double.